# Creating a list of widgets from map with keys and values

Tags: dart, flutter

If I have say a `SimpleDialog()` and it accepts `children[]` and I want to populate it from a `Map<int, String>`, how would I do that? I need both the key and value to create the child widget.

```
const optionsMap = {
    111:"First option",
    222:"Second option",
}
return SimpleDialog(
    title: Text('Choose one'),
    children: // I don't know what to put here
              // I want to have widgets based on optionsMap keys and values
)
```

I solved it by creating a `List<Widget>` beforehand above the return statement, but just for convenience (and becoming better in Dart) I'd like to know if there's a way to do it inline.

Comment: You could use the Map.map() function to obtain a new Map<int, Widget> and then use this new map's values: `children : options.map((entry){ return MapEntry<int, Widget>(entry.key, /*here create the widget from entry.key and entry.value*/);}).values.toList()`.

Comment: Using a `ListView` and converting your map into a list should work

Answer (score 56, accepted):

Update answer to incorporate @lrn 's comment

You can use `map`

```dart
const optionsMap = {
    111:"First option",
    222:"Second option",
}     
    return SimpleDialog(
        title: Text('Choose one'),
        children: optionsMap.entries.map((entry) {
          var w = Text(entry.value);
          doSomething(entry.key);
          return w;
        }).toList());
;
```

Comment: I want to be able to access both keys and values.

Comment: Slightly simpler: `optionsMap.entries.map((entry) { var w = Text(entry.value); doSomething(key); return w; })`. So, instead of creating a map and using only the values, just create the values as an iterable.

Comment: @irn thanks, but did you try you code?  I think you will still ned to to have `toList()`

Comment: I didn't know about `entries` property, that makes dealing with maps so much easier.